# How do you access the attributes of a class instance from inside an array? (Swift)

Tags: arrays, class, swift

I can't figure out how. This is my code, I'm hoping to access the tastePrefrence and temperaturePreference attributes (attributes of the customer class), from outside of the array they're being stored in.

```
// Create Customers
    var arrayOfCustomers:[Customer] = []
    var index = 0
    for index; index < 10; index++ {
        var customer = Customer()
        customer.tastePreference = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10)))
        customer.temperaturePreference = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10)))
        arrayOfCustomers += [customer]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access members of an array by subscripting, then the properties as normal. For example:

```
let temperaturePreference = arrayOfCustomers[0].temperaturePreference
```

For the first customer in the array.